# How to fix Google Play Services 2 Library install to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-play-services

I've tried to follow https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html instructions in Eclipse for Mobile Developers (Juno), but am getting multiple errors with the library package after importing the library project into my workspace.  I fixed the AndroidManifest.xml error it reported, but now I can't open the project in Eclipse saying the .project  description file contains invalid information.  So much for a simple install.  I've tried uninstalling it, redownloading it, and I still get the multiple errors.  Any suggesions how to get it working?

Answer (score 53):

There is a misleading step in step 3 of http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html:

> Copy the
>   /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
>   library project into the source tree where you maintain your Android
>   app projects.
>
> If you are using Eclipse, import the library project into your
>   workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code
>   into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to
>   import it.

Don't do the first copy.  Instead just do the second part and check the box that says "Copy projects into workspace".  I found that if I did the first part I would end up with empty xml files.

Comment: +1 because, You mentioned: Instead just do the second part and check the box that says "Copy projects into workspace"

Comment: So after copying project to workspace, what happens when there is an update?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#sample_code
```

You would get errors while opening an activity mentioned in the sample code. That is because android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity is not added to your build path. Hover over the error and click on "Fix Project Setup". It would ask you to add the lib to the build path. Say Yes and enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

If your google_pay_services/libproject is empty (mine was empty) and looks like installed in sdk manager, first delete google play services from sdk manager, install it again and follow the steps in the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try *Window > Android SDK Manager > Extras > Google play service > Delete package*.

And then re-install that package again:

*File > Import,* select Android *> Existing Android Code into Workspace*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I went to Properties->Java Build Path and clicked on the Projects tab.  Then I added google-play-services_lib using the Add button.  This got me this run-time exception:

E/AndroidRuntime(9469): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

So then I changed the main.xml file entry from this:

```
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

to this:

```
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

And FINALLY, it runs, but NOW no map due to authorization failure.  So I am off on another search.

thanks Google for making it so complicated and for posting incorrect instructions!