# How to draw route directions from a marker to another one ? Googlemaps v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, android-drawable

Here is my code :

```
    public class MyGoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.googlemap);

            GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            LatLng Paris= new LatLng(64.711696, 12.170481);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("LolluSaba").position(Paris));
            LatLng Cinema= new LatLng(34.711696, 2.170481);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Pseudo").position(Cinema));
       }
    }
```

And i like to draw a route from Paris to Cinema. How can I do it very simply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have two points so send it through google json which provides to draw route
  between two points. See this example.

[Route direction between two location](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you have the coordinates of the two points you want to draw, you can get the route from google using the following methods:

```
class GetDirection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MapaAnunciante.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Drawing the route, please wait!");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String stringUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + origin+ "&destination=" + destination+ "&sensor=false";
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpconn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            if (httpconn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(httpconn.getInputStream()),
                        8192);
                String strLine = null;

                while ((strLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(strLine);
                }
                input.close();
            }

            String jsonOutput = response.toString();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonOutput);

            // routesArray contains ALL routes
            JSONArray routesArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
            // Grab the first route
            JSONObject route = routesArray.getJSONObject(0);

            JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            String polyline = poly.getString("points");
            pontos = decodePoly(polyline);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        for (int i = 0; i < pontos.size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLng src = pontos.get(i);
            LatLng dest = pontos.get(i + 1);
            try{
                //here is where it will draw the polyline in your map
                Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude,                dest.longitude))
                    .width(2).color(Color.RED).geodesic(true));
            }catch(NullPointerException e){
                Log.e("Error", "NullPointerException onPostExecute: " + e.toString());
            }catch (Exception e2) {
                Log.e("Error", "Exception onPostExecute: " + e2.toString());
            }

        }
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}

private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Where `origin` and `destination` are two strings containing the lat and lng of the points, formatted like "-1.0,2.0":

```
 String origin = "64.711696,12.170481";
 String destination = "34.711696,2.170481";
```

To execute it, just call `new GetDirection().execute();`

Hope it helps!

Comment: So i had to create an other class which is Get Direction ? Can I had this to Class MyGoogleMapActivity ?

Comment: Yes, you can create it inside your MyGoogleMapActivity, I created my GetDirection inside my activity too!

Comment: I have some errors : dialog cannot be resolved to a variable, MapaAnunciante cannot be resolved to a type, pontos cannot be resolved to a variable and The method decodePoly(String) is undefined for the type GetDirection. What should I do ?

Comment: oh sry... MapaAnunciante is your MyGoogleMapActivity, pontos is defined as private List<LatLng> pontos;, the method decodePoly is just under the class, it should work

Comment: Just declares a private ProgressDialog dialog;, so there will be a dialog while it draws the route

Comment: I created this inside of MyGoogleMapActivity and how can i call it because it shows me that -The type GetDirection is never used locally

Comment: It's like I said on the answer, you just call new GetDirection().execute(); when you want to draw the route... but call it after the String origin = "64.711696,12.170481"; String destination = "34.711696,2.170481";

Comment: I see this on the LogCat - the google play services resources were not found. check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included. And we i clic on my app i can see "Drawing the route, please wait!" and after 2 sec it's my app close immediately.

Comment: Oh, that's because you didn't link the google-play-services to your projects. If you don't link it, you cannot use Google Maps in your app. You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142496/how-to-fix-google-play-services-2-library-install-to-eclipse, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371725/add-google-play-services-to-eclipse-project, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715716/how-to-add-google-play-services-jar-project-dependency-so-my-project-will-run-an

Comment: Before try to draw the route. I had the possibility of showing the map. And i could mark my current location too. I already linked it.

Comment: No. I still have the same problem. (I see this on the LogCat - the google play services resources were not found. check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included. And we i clic on my app i can see "Drawing the route, please wait!" and after 2 sec it's my app close immediately.)

Comment: That's because you don't have the google play services linked in your project, so your google maps won't work. You need to follow the 3 tutorials I have sent to you on the previous comments

Comment: Before I try to do the route, I could see my map and I had already linked google play services in my project.

Comment: And if you doesn't call the asynctask that show the route, does is show the map? or it throws another exception?

Comment: if I do only class GetDirection { i have an error which is The method onPreExecute() is undefined for the type Object And if I do this : /*protected void onPreExecute() { super.onPreExecute(); dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyGoogleMapActivity.this); dialog.setMessage("Drawing the route, please wait!"); dialog.setIndeterminate(false); dialog.setCancelable(false); dialog.show(); }*/ I can see the map as before but i don't see the route ...

Comment: @giacomoni I do exactly like your codes, but it didn't draw anything!

Comment: {   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",   "routes" : [],   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"} Please suggest for this

Answer (score 2):

You Need to use the Directions API in combination with the `Android Maps util Lib`

1. Get the `Encoded Polyline` String from the Directions Api.
2. Decode the encoded string using Maps Util Lib into a list of lat/lng's (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/#poly-encoding)
3. Draw the Polyline on the map using the lat/lngs!

Answer (score 0):

First a List of LatLng you need

`List<LatLng> ls_pos=new ArrayList<>();`

After that In OnMapReady

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
   if (ls_pos.size() >= 2) {

 mMap.addPolyline(newPolylineOptions().addAll(ls_pos).width(10).color(Color.RED).visible(true).clickable(true));

     ls_pos.clear
```

That's Work for me.