# Admob in Java file causes app to close

Tags: java, android, admob

I added Admob to my app, but it causes it to close when I open the app.

In the logcat, I found this: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView"

I searched for that and it talked about using an older version of the Admob SDK

I'm using the Google Play SDK google-play-services_lib.

Here is my Java file.

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    WebView myWebView;
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        String url = "file:///android_asset/index.html";

            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            //next line explained below
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);


            AdView adView = new AdView(this);

            // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
            // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.adView);

            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);

            AdRequest request = AdRequest();
            adView.loadAd(request);
    }



    private AdRequest AdRequest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack() == true){
            myWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
05-25 17:29:26.038: E/AndroidRuntime(23325): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jkb.pocketwelderhelperfree-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.jkb.pocketwelderhelperfree-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33392069/277345

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your app you are referencing `com.google.ads.AdView` which is the old (6.4.1 and before) Admob classes. Find out where that is and remove it.

Perhaps in your XML?
Or in a library that you are including?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Perhaps I'm late but it could help others.

Check this please: In the step 3 of [Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) says:

> In your app project, reference Google Play services library project.
>   See Referencing a Library Project for Eclipse for more information on
>   how to do this.
>
> **Note: You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied
>   to your development workspace—you should not reference the library
>   directly from the Android SDK directory**.

**Solution: Don't do the copy manually. Instead just check the box in Eclipse that says "Copy projects into workspace"**

I did it so and everything worked again.

Thanks to this StackOverFlow question: [How to fix Google Play Services 2 Library install to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142496/how-to-fix-google-play-services-2-library-install-to-eclipse)